# Why is the second static variable assignment takes effect not the first one?

Tags: php, static, static-variables

```
function track_times() {
static $i = 0;
$i++;
static $i = 5;
return $i;
}

echo track_times() . "\n";
echo track_times() . "\n";
```

The result is:

```
6
7
```

I know people don't use `static` variables in this way, just can't explain the result. The result implies the second assignment takes effect, but `$i` increments itself before the assignment, so why the first invocation of the function returns 6?

Comment: but why do you want to write this pattern? doesn't sound logical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static declarations are resolved in compile-time. You are incrementing it during runtime. Therefore you are incrementing it after it's already declared as 5. See also http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: If I remove the `static` in the first assignment, the result would be '5, 5', so how does it make a difference?